# NASM moving from memory to register and back not performing as expected

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am new to assembly. In short I have no idea what I am doing and why the thing respond the way it does. I am using nasm, however I am not allowed to use any c functions. This has co compile and run using nasm assembly for intel x86 64bit. Here is some code:

```
    section .data

    x: dd 0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    mov eax,0
    mov edi,0
    mov rsi,x
    mov edx,1
    syscall

    mov r9,x ;My problem was here, should be mov r9,[x]
    mov word [x],r9w 

    mov eax,1
    mov edi,1
    mov rsi,x
    mov edx,1
    syscall

    mov eax,1            ; The system call for exit (sys_exit)
    mov ebx,0            ; Exit with return code of 0 (no error)
    int 80h;
```

so all I am doing here is reading input from the console, saving that in x. then move that to register r9 and then back to x.

```
input 5
```

.

```
output
```

I tried doing the normal xor, and mov r9,0. I can see that it does have get a value ass if I add 200, it gives me an output of

```
U
```

My only goal for doing this is to try and get a deeper understanding of how this works.
thanx.

Comment: single step your code in a debugger.  That will help your understanding a *lot*.  You're storing the low 16 bits of `x`'s address into `x`.  IDK why you're doing that.

Comment: I am trying to store the value within x in x. no reason other than understanding. while working on an assignment I stumbled upon irregularities in my output. I boiled it down to a problem I have moving to and from registers and memmory

Comment: [NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2)

Comment: What OS is this? Certainly not Linux; else you read your byte into the null address.

Comment: He didn't read the byte into the null address. `mov rsi,x` moved the address of `x` to _RSI_, `mov edi,0` set FD to STDIN, and `mov edx,1` said to read 1 byte. _EAX_ = 0 is `sys_read` . The real problem is that `mov r9,x` should probably have been `mov r9w,[x]` . The square brackets would be needed since we want to move what is at that address `x`, not the address itself.

Comment: @Joshua : his syscall read is correct

Comment: oky, thanx, the mov r9,[x] worked. Now I understand the reference vs value.

Comment: It is preferred with 64-bit code to use syscall rather than int 0x80. Your exit syscall preferably would have been a syscall with something like `mov eax, 60` `xor edi, edi` `syscall` . You can find a list of the 64-bit Linux SysCalls in Ryan Chapman's blog . EAX=60 is the exit system call with the return value in _RDI_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to store the value within x in x

So you're trying to load x's value and then store it back again unmodified?

IDK if you understand that "x's value" *is* what's stored at the memory address marked with label `x`.

---

Anyway, also note that you've reserved 4 bytes at address `x` (with `dd`).   You pass that address to `sys_read(0, x, 1)` to get the kernel to store up to 1 byte of input from stdin there.

Then you put the address of `x` into R9 with `mov r9, x`.  (I think you meant to do `mov rsi, [x]`, which would be an 8-byte load.)

Then you store the low 16-bits of R9 into x with `mov [x], r9w

Then you pass the address of `x` to sys_write, writing one byte to stdout.

So IDK what you're hoping to accomplish here, but perhaps that helps explain what your code actually does.

To learn more, **single-step in a debugger (like gdb) and watch register values change**.  See the gdb usage notes at the bottom of the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

Comment: yes, That is what I meant, thank you. I did not try to accomplish anything with my code, rather to understand what I am doing. the problem lies in when to use the []. My goal was to single out my problem in my code, and post it here rather than my whole assignment.

Comment: I think the title of his question was better worded than the question itself. I think all along his goal was _moving from memory to register and back_

Comment: @Elterado: you generally shouldn't edit the answer into your question.  Once you understand what the problem was, you can often go back and improve the question to be more clear, but answers still belong as answers.  The question still reads as a confusing mess.  IDK what the `input 5` code block is supposed to be, and it took me a few minutes of squinting at your question to figure what the heck it said.  You can use backticks to get code formatting in-line in a sentence, BTW.